# Rename the Model in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to pass a collection of objects from a controller to the view, using a `Model`.

Is it possible to rename the `Model` so that my view is readable?

e.g. instead of using `@foreach (var question in Model)`,

is there a way to say `@foreach (var question in questions)`?

```
// HomeController.cs

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var repo = new QuestionRepository();
        var questions = repo.FindAll();

        return View(questions);
    }
}

// Index.cshtml

@model IEnumerable<MyDomain.Models.Entity.Question>

<div class="questions-wrap">
    <div class="questions">

        @foreach (var question in Model)
        {
            // Do stuff with the question
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No it's not possible (unless you do `var questions = Model;` at the top of your view), but why do you think using `Model` is unreadable?

Comment: It's just my preference, but I feel reading `foreach (question in questions)` makes more sense than `foreach (question in Model)`.

Comment: Well, er, it represents the model, seems pretty readable to me!

Comment: Yeah, that's true. Anyway, I think using `var questions = Model`, will satisfy my aesthetical requirements. If you can post that as an answer, that would be great. Thanks!

Comment: It seems the @jom has nabbed my code and answered anyway. Though another option would be to have a model with a `Questions` property.

Comment: @DavidG Lol sorry, seriously didn't see your comment prior to answering. OP can remove the vote if he likes. Or I'll just delete it so you can post yours. Is that fair enough?

Comment: @DavidG what do you mean by model with a Questions property? something like `Model.Questions`?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could reassign it to a variable if that makes you happy. :)

```cshtml
@model IEnumerable<MyDomain.Models.Entity.Question>

@{
    var questions = Model;
}

<div class="questions-wrap">
    <div class="questions">

        @foreach (var question in questions)
        {
            // Do stuff with the question
        }
    </div>
</div>
```